# Test output using curses

Tags: ruby, rspec, curses

I'm trying to make a test using rspec for my simple othello app using curses. I need to make sure that the terminal prints an output as below:

[image]

To make the output more interactive, I use curses. When I check the output, it gives me a combination of ANSI sequence code (I guess):

```
[?1049h[1;23r(B[m[4l[?7h[?1h=[39;49m[?1h=[39;49m(B[m[H[2J[4;43H(B[0;1m[32m
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐[5;43H
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │[6;43H
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤[7;43H
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │[8;43H
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤[9;43H
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │[10;43H
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤[11;43H
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │[12;43H
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤[13;43H
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │[14;43H
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤[15;43H
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │[16;43H
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤[17;43H
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │[18;43H
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤[19;43H
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │[20;43H
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘[39m(B[m[20;43H[?[23;1H[?1049l[?1l>
```

How should I test if the result is like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the output of a curses application to the standard output because that is the default for `initscr` (it helps if the application does not ask for input). If you capture the output into a file, you can do whatever analysis you need.

For the simple example given, curses is painting the screen once, using ANSI escape sequences for cursor movement (the parts ending with "H"), color (the ones with "m"), and a few others.

I said simple - if there were large blank areas on the screen, then curses would jump over those, and the residue without the escape sequences would look less like the actual screen.  But since your lines are close together, it is less costly to just write the text with a few blanks as needed.

If you limit yourself to simple examples like that, then all you need to do is to strip the escape sequences out and compare the text.  For a more general approach, you might consider making a screen-dump utility using [winnstr](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_instr.3x.html) (so that your application could dump the text from the screen as curses shows it).